# How to implement key controls for a Java program?

Tags: java, key, awt, controls, keylistener

This is a method in the main class of my program. It has the controls that I want (pressing 'i' will call Field.ship.push(0, -1)), but I need to know how to implement them in the program so it actually works? Please tell me what I need to add to the main program so that I can use the controls while I'm playing the game. Thanks

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
    char eventChar = event.getKeyChar();
    if (eventChar == 'i') {
        Field.ship.push(0, -1);
    } else if (eventChar == 'j') {
        Field.ship.push(-1, 0);
    } else if (eventChar == 'k') {
        Field.ship.push(0, 1);
    } else if (eventChar == 'l') {
        Field.ship.push(1, 0);
    } else if (eventChar == 'a') {
        Field.addBullets();
    }

}
```

Comment: Still waiting for you to start accepting answers from your other questions.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a KeyListener.

See [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for the reasons why you should not use a KeyListener as well as an example using `Key Bindings`, which is the preferred approach, to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, its a big milestone.

Comment: So you're not going to help, is that it?